# Unable to kill a bash script but using kill command

Tags: bash, scripts

Ive got a bash script running but I need to kill it.I have got the PID by using `ps` which shows:

```
 127140 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 128463 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

I know that the PIDF is 127140 but when I ran `sudo kill -9 127140` the terminal closes but the process is still running?

Have also tried to use to kill the script by name.
`ps -aux | grep script_name`

`killall script_name inotifywait`

Comment: 127140 isthe PID of your terminals bash, not of a running script. Isthe script running in the same terminal ? `ps` only shows processes in the current session.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I closed the terminal window the script was ran but it still kept running. I ended up restarting my machine but any idea why I couldn't kill it? was it because I had closed the initial terminal window where i had executed the script